# How to render only one frame using cloth simulation

Tags: python, rendering, cloth-simulation

I want to render image including cloth simulation with python script.
I'm pinning cloth at one of the vertexes and rendering some images rotating camera around it.
Now I'm doing to set frame,

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(target_frame)
```

but, it makes cloth like this,[image]

when I use animation, it looks good, I want to make it like this with python script...
[image]
Is there any good way to solve this problem??
Can anyone help me??

Comment: Have you tried to set the sim into the cache before?  bpy.ops.ptcache.bake_all(bake=True)

Comment: Similarly to physics, bake to the frame you wish to render. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146829/15543  @lemon ditto.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108077/save-mesh-via-python-scripting-at-a-given-frame

Comment: I could fix it with bake! Thank you so much!